# Como destruir um $scope.$watch?

Tags: angularjs

Eu tenho o seguinte `$scope.$watch` no controller de uma diretiva que eu criei:

```
var interval;

$scope.$watch('active', function () {

    if ($scope.active == true) {

        interval = $interval(function () {

            if ($scope.current >= $scope.to) {

                // Quero destruir o Watch aqui.

                return $interval.cancel(interval);
            }

            $scope.current += amounth;

        }, 10);

    }
});
```

Quando o valor cair dentro da condição indicada acima por um comentário, eu gostaria que o `$watch` fosse desligado/destruído, pois não vou precisar mais detectar alterações no valor `active`.

Existe alguma maneira de destruir/desabilitar um watch em Angular?

Comment: Na declaração do seu watch vc atribui ele em uma variável. Quando você quiser destrui-lo você executa a função que estará na variavel: `var meuWatch = $scope.$watch('active', function ()...; meuWatch();`

Comment: Isso funciona igual  o settimeout do Jquery?

Comment: `setTimeout` não é do jQuery, é do Javascript. E não, não é a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu particularmente achei meio estranho a forma de se fazer isso, e desconheço caso tenha outra. Porém, basta você declarar uma variável para o **whatch** e "chamá-lo" quando não deseja mais observar. Seu exemplo seria algo parecido com isso:

```
var interval;
var watchAtivo = $scope.$watch('active', function () {
    if ($scope.active == true) {
        interval = $interval(function () {
            if ($scope.current >= $scope.to) {
                // Destroi o watch aqui
                watchAtivo ();
                return $interval.cancel(interval);
            }
            $scope.current += amounth;
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

Caso queira mais explicação sobre o assunto, [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13651578/4843158) possui mais explicações.

Answer (score 6):

Todas as funções de monitoramento de escopo retornam uma função de desregistro:

- `$applyAsync`
- `$on`
- `$watch`
- `$watchGroup`
- `$watchCollection`

Para desregistrar um *listener*, simplesmente chame sua função de desregistro:

```
var dereg = $scope.$watch('target', function () {}); // Inicia monitoramento
dereg(); // Encerra monitoramento
```

Fonte: [Documentação AngularJS, $rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)